# Regex with imask.js

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to create a Mask on my input so that the user is forced to enter a value in the format 'YYYY Text' (YYYY being a year but I can not check its validity, I just check that they are numbers). My problem is that it is not working with this regular expression that is good :

```
var element = document.getElementById('Cline');
var maskOptions = {
        mask: /^[0-9]{4} [a-zA-Z]+$/
    };
var mask = IMask ( element, maskOptions );
```

Here is the HTML of my input:

```html
    <input type="text" class="field__form-input" id="Cline" name="Cline">
```

the problem is that for example, the mask works with an expression that I took from the website which is this one:

```html
var element = document.getElementById('Cline');
var maskOptions = {
  mask: /^[1-6]\d{0,5}$/
};
var mask = IMask(element, maskOptions);
```

but when I put the news, the input is blocked and I can no longer write anything in it, as if no character was accepted. And yet the one I put is correct because I tested it without the mask on another input, and there no worries

Comment: The regular expression seems to be ok, can you specify what “it is not working” means, exactly? What's the expected behaviour vs. the actually observed behaviour? Error messages?

Comment: What is your Html code? What does the console say (if anything) ? Have you included the library ? Have you tested with a simpler regexp ? Have you tried to replicate the samples from imask.js site?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your regular expression accepts *any prefix* of a valid input, as also the [imask](https://imask.js.org/guide.html#masked-base) documentation highlights.

It is important to realise that the user will enter the input character by character, and at each instance the input should be allowed when it can **lead** to a valid input when completely entered. Currently that is not the case as your regex requires the 4 digits, the space and at least one letter, which does not allow that the user enters a first digit, and so they cannot enter anything.

So do this:

```
    mask: /^(\d{0,4}|\d{4} [a-zA-Z]*)$/
```

Snippet:

```js
var element = document.querySelector('input');
var maskOptions = {
  mask: /^(\d{0,4}|\d{4} [a-zA-Z]*)$/
};
var mask = IMask(element, maskOptions);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/imask/6.4.3/imask.min.js"></script>

<input>
```